# Low download speed in Beta ios (Fabric)

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

In our work we use fabric to share builds to the testes. 
On iOS devices we use Beta app.

Last days builds started downloading for too long. We check all connections on our side, everything ok. Than we check and find out that Fabric servers have upload speed about `300kbit/sec`.

1. Is any one has the same problem?
2. How can we increase the speed limit?

Comment: Are you still seeing these slow speeds or was it a temporary slow down? Can you let me know where you're geographically located?

Comment: @Alexizamerican I recheck. The average speed is 200-300 kbit/sec. I located in Kharkiv Ukraine.

Comment: thanks. I'll have the team look into this and it's likely a temporary issue.. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can adjust on your end to make this go faster.

Comment: Seconding this issue - I routinely am unable to download Crashlytics builds. Download just hangs. Have tested in numerous geos including US, Mexico, Asia.

Comment: Problem for me too, for a couple of months now.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Very very slow download speeds! now!

Comment: It happens often. Download speed is very slow. Today is not even downloading a year old app build.